# How to reuse a for variable in django

Tags: html, django, django-templates

I'm trying to display me df in a table to my web app (without using .tohtml because I need a dynamic table).
It seems that I can't use the key/column variable from my loop :

```
<table id='bdd_table'>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            {% for header in BDD_Data %}
            <th> {{header}} </th>
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {%  for key in BDD_Data_size %}
        <tr>
            {% for column in BDD_Data %}
            <td> {{BDD_Data[column][key]}} </td>
            {% endfor %}    
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}

    </tbody>
</table>
```

My error:
[image: error]

I think I've any problems with my data because if I write `{{column}} / {{key}}` instead of `{{BDD_Data[column][key]}}` it displays all the values from my dataframe.

Comment: Is `BDD_Data` a list or dict?

Comment: @arulmr it is a dataframe

Comment: I haven't used a Dataframe in Django templates before. You can try converting the Dataframe to Dict and pass it to the template. That might work.

Comment: Thank you for your help. If I don't find any solution I will go for dictionnaries but I prefer stay with dataframe which is really powerfull and easy for working with data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick was to use mydataframe.values :

```
<table id='bdd_table'>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            {% for header in BDD_Data %}
            <th> {{header}} </th>
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {%  for value in BDD_Data.values %}
        <tr>
            {% for cell in value %}
            <td> {{cell}} </td>
            {% endfor %}    
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}

    </tbody>
</table>
```